# android:allowBackup="false" giving error "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

Tags: android

I am working on an application, which was working fine before Android studio and gradle updates. Issue is we have developed the application in a way where some data is stored in DB and Preferences. But now even during complete reinstall of application fetching the OLD local sqlite DB.

Possible cause of this seems: `android:allowBackup="true"` in Application Tag(Manifest) and solution may lie in `android:allowBackup="false"` as per the google developer documentation.

But on assigning `android:allowBackup="false"` is giving me following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Even in log file I am unable to understand the cause of the issue.

Comment: Can you post your error logs also?

Answer (score 4):

After `android:allowBackup="false"` add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup`.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#attribute_markers

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I also got the same solution.